# Bootstrap Carousel Arrows Won't Respond to z-index change

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have modified the html for my bootstrap arrow icons in a carousel from the original layout so that the glyphicon's are the hyperlink for prev and next.  The problem that I am having is that when the carousel is on a small screen the elements that are appended in carousel-inner (see code, appending is done with d3) seem to overlap with the left glyphicon and it can't be used to go to the previous slide. This does not happen with a larger screen. (note that they are initially hidden but I show them when the page is built)  Although I have prev and next bound to keyboard arrows this can still cause confusion for some users.  I have tried making sure that the left arrow is assigned a position in the CSS and then given the highest z-value on the page but it still does not work.  Is there another means for making this work?

```
<div class="carousel-wrapper">
    <div id="defect-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
        <!-- Controls -->
        <div class="left carousel-control" style="display:none;">
        <a href="#defect-carousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
         </div>
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-inner"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="right carousel-control" style="display:none;">
        <a href="#defect-carousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could we take a peek at your CSS? Are you setting the positioning / `z-index` to the actual `span`, the `<a href>` or the actual `.carousel-control` parent?

Comment: I was assigning it to .carousel-control

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle / codepen / etc demonstrating the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by assigning the higher z-index to the left class instead of the carousel control or glyphicon classes.